# Error Launching MacOS application built with Clang

Tags: macos, clang

Recently I compiled an application with Clang compiler and address sanitizer, but the application cannot launch. I got this error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810
```

I can run the application if it is compiled with clang (without asan) or gcc

I cannot find a clue to this problem in order pages.

Does anyone have an idea what may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a permissions issue, so you should ensure you set your app's binary as executable.

Ie:

> sudo chmod +x /Applications/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo

I see from [this post that this might be a potential solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tweecode/3X7oJxxYHpg), but on the other hand [-10810 is a generic 'unknown' error code](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html) so it could be something else.

Hope this helps.